# Scroll Points / overflow-y breaking javascript function with window.pageYOffset

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page where I was using JS - specifically window.pageYOffset - and HTML data to change the inner HTML of the h1 footer, use l1 links to scroll the page to each section, and to add classes to each li when I reached the top of each section.work-page.

However, after I implemented CSS scroll points and added the div.container over the scrollable sections my javascript stopped working. Specifically when I set the overflow-y: scroll.

Basically when I made the div.container overflow-y: scroll; the doWork function stopped working and I can't figure out why.

^^^^ div.container in CSS

```js
const doWork = function () {


const p01Tag = document.getElementById("p01")
const p02Tag = document.getElementById("p02")
const p03Tag = document.getElementById("p03")
const p04Tag = document.getElementById("p04")
const container = document.querySelector("div.container")

  const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section.work-page")
  const clientTag = document.querySelector("h2.about")



  document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    const pixels = window.pageYOffset
      console.log(pixels)

    sections.forEach(section => {
      if(section.offsetTop - 400 <= pixels) {
        clientTag.innerHTML = section.getAttribute("data-client")

        if (section.hasAttribute("data-seen-1")) {
        p01Tag.classList.add("move")
      } else {
        p01Tag.classList.remove("move")
      }

        if (section.hasAttribute("data-seen-2")) {
        p02Tag.classList.add("move")
      } else {
        p02Tag.classList.remove("move")
      }

      if (section.hasAttribute("data-seen-3")) {
      p03Tag.classList.add("move")
    } else {
      p03Tag.classList.remove("move")
    }

    if (section.hasAttribute("data-seen-4")) {
    p04Tag.classList.add("move")
  } else {
    p04Tag.classList.remove("move")
  }

      }
    })

  })


// scrolling between projects ============================

function smoothScroll(target, duration) {
  const targetTag = document.querySelector(target);
  let targetPosition = targetTag.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  const startPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  let startTime = null;

  function animation(currentTime) {
    if(startTime === null ) startTime = currentTime;
    const timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
    const run = ease(timeElapsed, startPosition, targetPosition, duration);
    window.scrollTo(0,run);
    if (timeElapsed < duration) requestAnimationFrame(animation)
  }

function ease(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d / 2;
  if (t < 1) return c / 2 * t * t + b;
  t--;
  return -c / 2 * (t * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
}

  requestAnimationFrame(animation)
}

p01Tag.addEventListener("click", function() {
  smoothScroll('section.fn-up', 800)
})

p02Tag.addEventListener("click", function() {
  smoothScroll('section.cameron', 800)
})

p03Tag.addEventListener("click", function() {
  smoothScroll('section.truax', 800)
})

p04Tag.addEventListener("click", function() {
  smoothScroll('section.romero', 800)
})


}

doWork()

const doInfo = function () {
  const toggleTag = document.querySelector("a.contact")
  const sectionTag = document.querySelector("section.info-page")

  toggleTag.addEventListener("click", function () {
    sectionTag.classList.toggle("open")

    if (sectionTag.classList.contains("open")) {
      toggleTag.innerHTML = "Close"
    } else {
      toggleTag.innerHTML = "Info"
    }
  })
}

doInfo()
```

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  }


body {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #050505;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.1;
}


header {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.contact {
  float: right;
}

ul {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}


p {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Info page -------------------- */
section.info-page {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100vh;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;

  transition: top 0.5s;
}

section.info-page.open {
top: 0;
}

/* Work page ------------------------*/
div.container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  /* WHEN WE ADD THIS OVERFLOW SETTING IN ORDER TO GET THE CSS SCROLL SNAP POINTS TO WORK IT BREAKS THE JAVASCRIPT */
 /* overflow-y: scroll; */
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.work-info {
  width: 13vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-right: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

div.work-info li {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

div.work-info li.move {
  transform: translateX(15px);
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #979797;
}

section.work-page {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;

}


section.work-page img {
  max-width: 60vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- hidden modal that runs off of the info.js script -->
  <section class="info-page">
   <h1>
    Hello
   </h1>
</section>

  <header>
  <a class="contact" href="#">Info</a>
  </header>
  
  <!-- objects that get new classes with javascript on pageYOffset -->
  <div class="work-info">
    <ul>
      <li id="p01" data-number="FN-UP Magazine"><a href="#">01</a></li>

      <li id="p02" data-number="Cameron Tidball-Sciullo"><a href="#">02</a></li>

      <li id="p03" data-number="Jacob Truax"><a href="#">03</a></li>

      <li id="p04" data-number="Alexander Romero"><a href="#">04</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<!-- scollable sections using the scroll points and triggering the pageYOffset -->
<div class="container">
  <section class="work-page fn-up" data-client="FN-UP Magazine" data-seen-1="yes">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="lib/fn-up.png">
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="work-page cameron" data-client="Cameron Tidball-Sciullo" data-seen-2="yes">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="work-page truax" data-client="Jacob Truax" data-seen-3="yes">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="lib/old.png">
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="work-page romero" data-client="Alexander Romero" data-seen-4="yes">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <h2 class="about">FN-UP Magazine</h2>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem because when I convert your code to a snippet everything seems to work. And as *Will* said, please, try to create a MCV example.

Comment: @Will I cleaned up the code and added a code snippet. Please let me know what else I can do in order to help solve this problem

Comment: @David just added a code snippet, and attempted to rephrase the question. Basically adding the div.container with the css of overflow-y: scroll added a bug to my javascript. Trying to figure out how to get around it. Thanks!

Comment: It's runnable, but I'm still not certain what we're looking at. Can you delete some code and still show the problem? We need to try to get it down to `minimal`. It looks like the `doWork()` function is missing, but that might not be involved? I'm not sure.

Comment: @Will I shortened it down as much as I possible could. I even removed the part that breaks the script so you can see how it normally runs. If you add back in the overflow setting on the div.container you will see how the scroll snap points start to work but how the doWork() function stops.

Comment: Ok, now I understand you. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a event listener to the page's `Document` object.

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
```

Then you calculate the number of pixels the document is currently scrolled along the vertical axis using [`window.pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset).

```
const pixels = window.pageYOffset
```

When you set the CSS attribute `overflow-y` to `scroll` in the `div.container` element, new scrollbars appears on the window. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Values):

> **scroll**
>
> Content is clipped if necessary to fit the padding box. Browsers display scrollbars whether or not any content is actually clipped. (This prevents scrollbars from appearing or disappearing when the content changes.) Printers may still print overflowing content.

From that moment on, you are not scrolling the `document`, you are scrolling `div.container`. That won't trigger you `scroll` event.

You need to bound the event to the `div` element:

```
const container = document.querySelector("div.container")
container.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
```

And, instead of calculating how much `document` has scrolled, get the `scrollTop` property of the `div.container`:

```
const pixels = container.scrollTop
```

You need to make the same changes in whatever part of the code that involves the above calculations. In `smoothScroll()`:

```
// const startPosition = window.pageYOffset;
const startPosition = container.scrollTop;

// window.scrollTo(0,run);
container.scrollTo(0,run);
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. This is what I figured it was but the missing piece was the container.scrollTop. Appreciate it! 

While I have you, now the smoothScroll function is broken. I changed the startPosition to 
`const startPosition = container.scrollTop;`
and the window.scrollTo to this
`container.scrollTo(0,run);`

But now it just jumps and doesn't animate. Any idea why that would've happened?

Comment: @JacobTruax - You are welcome! I have updated my answer.

Comment: @JacobTruax - Wait : I just saw that you included in your comment the changes that I have suggested you... For me is working. Let me have a second look.

Comment: @JacobTruax - Could you double check that you changed all the JS and the CSS (uncomment `overflow-y: scroll;`). It is working for me and I can't find a reason it shouldn't work for you.

Comment: I created this fiddle with colored squares, because it makes it more obvious the smoothScroll animation is not working. Before it would actually scroll to the section but now it jumps. http://jsfiddle.net/ydjhezmx/

Comment: On Firefox 62.0.3 on Linux it is working. Which browser do you use?

Comment: You are right. Just checked on Firefox and Safari and it works, but not on Chrome